# I get an empty excel file after downloading with php from sql databse

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel

I have some problems. I have an mySQL database where i want to store some peronal files. I know it is not the best way to handle it but they are only some excel files so it shoeldnt be that big of a deal i thought. However i only download empty files or excel files with the PHP in it. THis is what is in my SQL table:

```
['name'] = The name of the file;
['mime'] = The type of file (application/vnd.ms-excel);
['size'] = The size of the data;
['data'] = And the data itself;
```

Also there is a user id for who can see the file.

This is what is in my download file:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
  $id=intval($_GET['id']);
  if($id <= 0)
  {
    die('Het opgegeven ID is niet correct');
  }
  else
  {
    $sql_facturen=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT mime, name, data FROM facturen WHERE id='" . $id . "'");
    echo '<p> doing query </p>';
    if($sql_facturen)
    {
      if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_facturen) == 1)
      {
        $row_facturen=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_facturen);
        header("Content-Length: " . $row_facturen['size']);
        header("Content-Type: " . $row_facturen['mime']);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" .basename( $row_facturen['name']));

        readfile($row_facturen['data']);
      }
      else
      {
        echo '<p>Geen factuur met dat id aanwezig</p>';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried multiple header configurations that i found on the web. I also tried echo instead of readfile. However stil not the text that should be in it. Any sugestions? I am using google chrome.

EDIT:
Here is my upload file:

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
                if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) 
                {
                    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
                    $mime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
                    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
                    $size = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);
            $year = $_POST['year'];
                    $user_id = $_GET['id'];

                    $sql_upload=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO facturen (name, mime, size, data, created, year, user_id) VALUES ('" . $name . "','" . $mime . "','" . $size . "','" . $data . "', NOW(), '" . $year . "','" . $user_id . "')");
            if ($sql_upload)
            {
                echo 'Bestand is succesvol ingevoerd';
            }
            else
            {
                        echo 'Error uploading';
                        echo mysqli_error($con);
            }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$fileSize = strlen($row_facturen['data']);
```

Send header as follows :

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$row_facturen['name'].'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . $fileSize);
echo $row_facturen['data'];
exit();
```

[Added from here in favor of user]

Save file into database:

```
$tmpName=$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];                     
$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$data = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
```

Also specify the mysql fieldtype(your data field) to `MEDIUMBLOB`

Comment: Sorry to say but is doesn't work. When i download the file, it is filled with the HTML of the website :(

Comment: What are you storing in your database actually? How do you store the file data in your table?

Comment: $tmpName=$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];                     $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);//content here
fclose($fp);